# How to save the functions in a for loop in python?

Tags: python

code:

```
funcs = []

for i in xrange(5):

    def func():
        print i, id(func)

    func()
    funcs.append(func)

print

for func in funcs:
    func()
```

ret:

```
0 139805502318064
1 139805502318184
2 139805502318304
3 139805502318424
4 139805502318544

4 139805502318064
4 139805502318184
4 139805502318304
4 139805502318424
4 139805502318544
```

Can I create some functions in for loop and save them?

Comment: Well, your code seems to work, so what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Doesn't that show it working? The `id`s are different. `i` is the same, but that's a different problem (it's accessing the global value of `i`, which is left at 4 after the loop).

Comment: The code does what was asked - although perhaps the output shows duplication ..